# New file shortcut in file explorer does not work anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updated from 1.34.0 to 1.36.1 and somehow I am not able to create new files with my keyboard shortcut in the file explorer.

I used to just press "a" in the file explorer to create a new file (and shift+A for a folder) and now it instead starts to filter files (see the picture below where I pressed "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" to show what I mean by "filtering files").

I am not working with a lot of files and already using the CTRL+E menu to search for files, where can I disable this feature or at least get my "new file/folder" shortcut working again ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here, as of vscode 1.36.1 the accepted answer is still valid:
https://superuser.com/questions/1417361/how-to-disable-file-filtering-in-vs-code-sidebar-explorer